# Social network dataset with features

Tags: data-request, social-media

For a university project, I need a social network dataset, preferably from Facebook. The problem is that there are many data sets on the Internet, but all I've found contain information only about which users are friends. What I need is relationships + basic info about the user (age, gender etc.). Is this kind of information available? If so, where I can find them?

Answer (score 1):

Here is some datasets that contains friendships and features for ego nodes.
[Facebook](https://snap.stanford.edu/data/ego-Facebook.html), [Google+](https://snap.stanford.edu/data/ego-Gplus.html), [Twitter](https://snap.stanford.edu/data/ego-Twitter.html)

But the following dataset is what you want i guess, it contains friendship relationships and features for every nodes: 
[Pokec Dataset](https://snap.stanford.edu/data/soc-pokec.html) 
Pokec is a social network like facebook that is viral in Slovakia.